# How can a Python app find out that it's running inside a Kubernetes pod?

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have a Python script that should have slightly different behaviour if it's running inside a Kubernetes pod.

But how can I find out that whether I'm running inside Kubernetes -- or not?

Comment: Can you just pass an argument to it if it's in that env? Or set a system env variable that you check in the script?

Answer (score 4):

An easy way I use (and it's not Python specific), is to check whether `kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local` resolves to an IP (you don't need to try to access, just see if it resolves successfully)

If it does, the script/program is running inside a cluster. If it doesn't, proceed on the assumption it's not running inside a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and set an environment variable to some value when deploying your script to the cluster, then in your script you just check if the environment variable is present and set.

**THE ENV FILE DEPLOYED TO CLUSTER:**

```
KUBERNETES_POD=TRUE
```

**SCRIPT:**

```py
import os

load_dotenv()
is_kube = os.getenv('KUBERNETES_POD',default=False)

if is_kube:
    print('in cluster')
```

Then just make sure you do not have the environment variable set locally so that the `is_kube` boolean defaults to `False`.

If you are running a Django application, you can get the host name from the request parameter passed to each view with the [`get_host`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host) method:

```py
def function_view(request):
    host = request.get_host()
        if host == 'your-cluster_ip.com'
            print('in cluster')
```